# adding an image to css breadcrumbs

Tags: javascript, html, css, breadcrumbs

I want to use these nice breadcrumbs [jsfiddle.net/orihadar/bugvgbf5/](http://jsfiddle.net/orihadar/bugvgbf5/1/) but I need to add image above each text, so each **LI** will include both an image and text under this image (both horizontally centered).
Any attempt to do so destroy the nice look of these breadcrumbs.
Any idea how can I do it?

Following is the CSS:

```
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#breadcrumbs-two{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

#breadcrumbs-two li{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 1em;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a{
  background: #ddd;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5); 
  position: relative;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a:hover{
  background: #99db76;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  margin-top: -1.5em;   
  border-width: 1.5em 0 1.5em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ddd #ddd #ddd transparent;
  left: -1em;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a:hover::before{
  border-color: #99db76 #99db76 #99db76 transparent;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  margin-top: -1.5em;   
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-left: 1em solid #ddd;
  right: -1em;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a:hover::after{
  border-left-color: #99db76;
}

#breadcrumbs-two .current,
#breadcrumbs-two .current:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
}

#breadcrumbs-two .current::after,
#breadcrumbs-two .current::before{
  content: normal;
}
```

Comment: you want to do it like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/bugvgbf5/3/

Comment: it would help if you could add a picture of what you are trying to achieve or at least the image width/height you want in your breadcrumb

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upload an image. innovation you understood what I meant just that the icon should be above the text, not on it's left side. The image should be something like 35X35px. Thank you.

Comment: I was able to update the JSFiddle to show what I need just need help with the triangles before and after. http://jsfiddle.net/orihadar/bugvgbf5/6/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

You need to be more clear on what you are trying to achieve here.

http://jsfiddle.net/bugvgbf5/4/

```
<ul id="breadcrumbs-two">


<li>
    <a>
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0dadd597898bbd33e37fe684fa07aa2d?s=24&d=identicon&r=PG"/>

        <br/>
    bkbgbhighb
    </a>
</li>
```